# How can I get Weka classifiers to use a lot less memory and CPU time?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have a training set with 250,000 instances, which is too large for Weka classifiers to handle (although the data loads into the Weka UI just fine, any attempt to run a non-trivial classifier results in an out-of-memory, even with the machine's entire 8GB RAM dedicated to JVM heap).

Because this involves geographical data, it should perform quite well if I cluster on latitude/longitude and train separate classifiers on each cluster.

Is there a way to do this easily on the Weka command-line or KnowledgeFlow, without having to mess with the ARFF file? (I prefer to keep a single large ARFF file so different split strategies can be evaluated within Weka)

I looked into Bagging and Cross-Fold Validation, but I don't think they are a fit for my problem, as I don't want the data split up at random, but kept together based on similarity of location.

Comment: 100k rows, 5 columns, gave WEKA 80GB (not 8, 80) and it wasn't enough. I feel your pain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding these two options when training the classifier has an **amazing** impact on performance, so it obviates the need to split the datasets:

```
-no-cv -v
```

Training time on RandomForest, J48, and LWL goes down to under 2 minutes where without these options the algorithms were non-terminating (after many hours) or ran out of memory.

**Previous answer based on file-splitting kept in case it helps someone with a REALLY large dataset:**

I have found a partial solution. The following command line (in Windows) will split the data in one ARFF file into ten separate ARFF files based on clustering (I'm using K-Means because it runs very fast, but will probably switch to EM or DBSCAN later):

> java -Xmx4096m -cp weka.jar
>   weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.AddCluster -i
>   %TEMP%\StreetSet.arff -o \temp\clusters.arff -W
>   "weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans -N 10 -num-slots 4"
>
> for /l %i in (1,1,10) do java -Xmx4096m -cp weka.jar
>   weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.RemoveWithValues -C last -L %i -V
>   -i \temp\clusters.arff -o \temp\cluster%i.arff

This not quite what I wanted, because with this approach I can't use the Experimenter to try different parameter combinations, and now it complicates the evaluation/testing of new instances, having to go through separate command-lines to split by cluster first. I was hoping this all to be transparently handled within a Weka meta-classifier.

Answer (score 1):

> it should perform quite well if I cluster on latitude/longitude

That depends on the area of values that the algorithm covers. If they are from all over the world, k-means might give you some surprising results. long/lat doesn't quite fit into the world that k-means assumes. [Specifically the average in the euclidean space doesn't match up with the average on the longitude/latitude space](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

> (I prefer to keep a single large ARFF file so different split strategies can be evaluated within Weka)

Yet you said it is too large to fit in memory? Without any overhead, assuming 2 d feature vectors (longitude and latitude) plus one output value, 250k*3*8 bytes is only 6 megabytes, maybe 12 MB with object overhead (such small arrays makes the headers relatively large in Java land). Even if your data was dense an D = 1000, your still only taking up a little more than 2 GB of memory.

I think you might have some confusion on what it is you really want to do and how to do it. Perhaps you should invest some more time in learning about ML before tackling your problem. 
[Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) has a nice enough intro course.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see you are skeptical that I would run out of memory. There is something non-linear about the memory usage. I can run fine with small sets, up to 50k items. Go higher and some algorithms start failing. My JVMs are set to a 4GB heap.

Comment: You still haven't told us what the dimension of your problem is. And you still seem confused on what you are doing (all 3 things you mentioned [memory issues, locally learned classifier, bagging] have no relation ship to each other). 



Lastly, Weka isn't a very good tool, and is notorious for using far more memory than it should. If you want to stick with Java, you can try [JSAT](https://code.google.com/p/java-statistical-analysis-tool/) (bias warning: I'm the author). But it will only help you so much if you don't understand what it is you are doing.

Comment: The only confusion here is Weka's inability to execute any non-trivial algorithm on any non-trivial amount of data. BTW in case it was not clear from my earlier comment, the Weka UI is perfectly capable of loading all 250K instaces. It's only when a classifier algorithm is run on it, that it breaks. The clustering algorithms seem to use less memory; K-means doesn't blow up and runs in a matter of seconds. While experimenting I noticed that the Bagging meta-classifier prevents the memory error, but it segregates my data at random which is not optimal. I may try JSAT tomorrow.

Comment: Then please correct your question. "I have a training set with 250,000 instances, which is too large to fit in memory." clearly implies that your data set on its own does not fit in memory. " but it segregates my data at random which is not optimal. "This is exactly what bagging is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited the question. OK, I looked into JSAT. It does seem impressive for a one-author project :-) Unfortunately it does not fit my needs. I'm looking to do as little programming as possible for this task. I already have an ARFF file I'd like to use without further manipulation. That doesn't seem possible with JSAT.

Comment: Your still missing lots of details, but from what you do have - [LVQLLC](https://code.google.com/p/java-statistical-analysis-tool/source/browse/trunk/JSAT/src/jsat/classifiers/neuralnetwork/LVQLLC.java) in JSAT actually does exactly what you asked (k-means like breakup of the data and a classifier learned locally). I'd still recommend you learn a bit more about ML.

Comment: Your LVQLLC seems comparable to Weka's LWL